# What is the source of these panels featuring Emperor Palpatine from the Star Wars comics?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

What is the source of these panels featuring Emperor Palpatine from the *Star Wars* comics?

[image: Panel 1]

[image: Panel 2]

[image: Panel 3]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first image is from *[Darth Vader (2017) #25](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader_(2017)_25)*

The second image is from [Star Wars (2020) #8](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2020)_8)

The third image is from [Darth Vader (2020) #1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader_(2020)_1)

Comment: If you're getting these images from Wookieepedia, it might interest you to learn that they have sourcing if you click on the picture; https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPw8h.jpg